# CAML query join error

Tags: sharepoint, inner-join, caml

I have a projected field query which is giving the below error.

> Invalid Field Type of Showfield in projected field definition for
>   'Field_Name'. Unable to add join related fields to the Query.[Error
>   0x80070057] Unable to execute query: Error 0x80070057 Unknown
>   SPRequest error occurred. More information: 0x80070057

I have checked the ALIAS too. It's the same one which I have used earlier which happens to be a lookup column from the same list.
 What could be the root cause for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the field which gave the error was a choice field and a choice field cannot be made a Lookup. Hope this will help somebody.